# Why does one thread stop the other thread from running?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was going to use threads for each sound in a game engine I'm making. The problem is, whenever I make a new thread that has a `while(true)` statement, the other thread stops running.

I made a class to test this, and it only prints "goodbye", not "hello". I was wondering how to make the two threads run at the same time.

```
public class testor {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        testor test=new testor();
        test.runTest();
    }
    class threadTest implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                System.out.println("goodbye");
            }

        }

    }
    public void runTest(){
        threadTest test=new threadTest();
        test.run();
        while(true){
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not starting a thread just by calling `run()`. Have a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: oooooohhhhhhhhhh, lol. Thanks

Comment: If your question is answered, mark the answer as answer (lots of answers in one sentence).

Answer (score 3):

Since you are doing  `test.run();` **you are only** calling the method of that class but not starting the thread.

So in order to answer your question: there is no such a ***thread stopping the other thread from running?*** because you have **only one** Thread that is looping for ever and printing the message `System.out.println("goodbye");`

If that method is not looping for ever, it would return to the `runTest` method and then you would see the `System.out.println("hello");`

## Summary:

For starting a `Thread` use the [Thread::start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) method and not the `run`.

Comment: Yes, but what's the answer to OP's question?

Comment: Well, ok, but I meant that a complete answer would describe how to actually start a thread.

Answer (score 2):

Using `(new ThreadTest()).run()` does not start a new `Thread`, but just invokes the `run()` method in the current thread.

To run the code in a separate thread do:

```
(new Thread(new ThreadTest())).start();
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're not creating a new thread. Just naming a class something containing "thread" will not make it a thread, and a `Runnable` is no thread - it's a class like any other, with no special semantics or behaviour.

It's only special in that you can pass it to a `Thread` for execution.

```
public class Testor {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Testor test=new Testor();
        test.runTest();
    }

    class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                System.out.println("goodbye");
            }
        }
    }

    public void runTest(){
        Thread testThread = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
        testThread.start();
        while(true){
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

You should probably also adhere to the Java coding standards regarding your class and variable names if you do not want your code to look like an alien when combined with most other existing Java code.

Additionally, multithreading is more than just being able to start a new thread. You should also read about synchronisation issues - it's more complicated to do correctly than you might imagine.

Answer (score -1):

Your `run` method contains an infinite loop.
The `runTest()` method creates the thread which means you'll have 2 execution stacks the main stack, and the runnable `threadTest` stack.
since you're running the thread method first that contains an infinite loop, you'll always get the output `"good Bye"`.

Remove the infinite loop from `run()` method.